# Binding to TimeSpan field with IMultiValueConverter

Tags: wpf

I am getting an exception for this binding

```
<TextBlock.Text>
  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource converter}" Mode="OneWay">
    <Binding Path="TimeSpanProperty" />
    <Binding Path="FormsttingOption" />
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>


// converter.Convert code
if (formsttingOption == DurationFormat.Minutes)
  return Math.Round(timeSpan.TotalMinutes);
else
  return duration;
```

Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='164' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

The converter will, based on formatting option, convert TimeSpan value. In above example, FormattingOption is minutes, which means that TimeSpan value will be converted to minutes (164).

For some reason Text property does not accept this value. Anyone knows the reason, and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error explains it quite nicely:

> Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='164' MultiBindingExpression:target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

It tells you that `TextBlock.Text` is of type `String` and your converter is not producting a valid value.

In your `IMultiValueConverter.Convert` method, ensure you are returning a `String`, i.e.

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var timeSpan = (TimeSpan)values[0];
    var formattingOption = (DurationFormat)values[1];
    if(formattingOption == DurationFormat.Minutes)
    {
        return Math.Round(timeSpan.TotalMinutes).ToString(culture);
    }
    return duration.ToString(); // TODO not sure where duration comes from
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. Still, I am curious why does then is Text able to bind directly to Int property? Who does the conversion then? AS for the solution, since I am using this converter in some editors, I need "real" values, not strings, so I am just going to use Label.Content instead.

Comment: @Goran I believe WPF uses the classes which derive from [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx#inheritanceContinued) however when you use an `IValueConverter` or `IMultiValueConverter` you remove this functionality.